# (C#) Run a command after a successful execution of FileIO.ReadTextAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, file-io, windows-store-apps

I'm setting the content of a RichEditBox through a file read operation like so:

```
Editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file));
```

But I want to run a few more commands only if and when the asynchronous read operation is complete. Juding by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701487?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1), something similar is possible in WinJS through a `.done()` command. But I'm using C# and XAML, so I need to find another way.

My guess is that this can be done using `AsyncStatus`.

I've tried setting up the following code, but I don't know what replace ?????? with:

```
AsyncStatus status = ??????;
if (status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
{
    // Do something.
}
else
{
    // An error occurred.
}
```

Is there some way to get this to work? Is there another (better?) method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Windows Store apps, so maybe I am missing something, but since you are awaiting the `FileIO.ReadTextAsync` call, your method will block until the `SetText` call is complete, so you can simply code the other commands after that:

```
Editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file));
// Do other stuff - ReadTextAsync will have finished by now.
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark is right, the method will return as soon as it kicks off the `ReadTextAsync` method and once it completes, if there is no error the `SetText` call will go ahead. Otherwise an exception will be thrown. You can catch that if you need to log an error etc.

```
public async void SetText(string file)
{
    try
    {           
        var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

        //ReadTextAsync succeeded, set text 
        Editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // error do something
        throw;
    }
}
```